# How do I set 2 columns so each entry is unique against both columns?

Tags: sql-server, unique-key

I have a record that holds 2 license "keys" (actually GUIDs). When a request comes to our service it includes a key (GUID) in the request. I then do a query looking for a record that has this value in either the column Key1 or Key2.

The purpose of this is users will use Key1 for everything. Then they discover that Key1 has become public. So they switch to Key2 and then after 15 minutes, change the value of Key1. Now the old Key1 value is of no use.

By having the 2 keys, it allows the switch over with no downtime.

I need any key value to be unique. Not that any pair of values is unique. Not that a value in Key1 is unique in all rows for Key 1. But that a new value is unique in all rows.Key1 and rows.Key2.

Is there a way to force this in Sql Server. Or do I need to do this myself with a select before doing an insert or update?

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| LicenseId | ApiKey1                              | APiKey2                              |
| 1         | af53d192-7fa3-4be0-b3d4-7efe17a397b5 | 1a87cc4a-1941-4af7-aeaa-bf9690f47eef |
| 2         | 5bbc2d06-ed6f-4444-aa22-73820dd6f3f6 | c2bdd9d9-fd47-4727-83f8-02ed0e7537e1 |
| 3         | 8acfa8b4-aa4b-41a7-9d3d-b6ba1eac838e | 30c18f2d-5d89-4e5d-8e8e-2d2b647d6ab6 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I need to insure if I am going to create record LicenseId = 4, that if it has ApiKey2 = 'af53d192-7fa3-4be0-b3d4-7efe17a397b5', that the insert will fail because that guid is ApiKey1 for LicenseId = 1.

Comment: Sample data would be helpful

Comment: @LukaszSzozda - I just added a sample table. thanks - dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most natural way to enforce this in the database is to put all keys in a single column.  Eg

```
create table ApiKeys
(
  LicenceId int, 
  KeyId int check (KeyId in (0,1)),
  constraint pk_ApiKeys primary key (LicenceId,KeyId),
  KeyGuid uniqueidentifier unique
)
```

Arguably having both the keys on the same row violates [1NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form), and certainly your desire for uniqueness across the two column *strongly suggests* that they belong to a single domain.

So instead of storing ApiKey1 and ApiKey2 on the same row, you store them on two separate rows.

So instead of

---

```
---------------
| LicenseId | ApiKey1                              | APiKey2                              |
| 1         | af53d192-7fa3-4be0-b3d4-7efe17a397b5 | 1a87cc4a-1941-4af7-aeaa-bf9690f47eef |
| 2         | 5bbc2d06-ed6f-4444-aa22-73820dd6f3f6 | c2bdd9d9-fd47-4727-83f8-02ed0e7537e1 |
| 3         | 8acfa8b4-aa4b-41a7-9d3d-b6ba1eac838e | 30c18f2d-5d89-4e5d-8e8e-2d2b647d6ab6 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

You would have:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
| LicenseId | KeyId | ApiKey                              |
| 1         | 0     | af53d192-7fa3-4be0-b3d4-7efe17a397b5|
| 1         | 1     | 1a87cc4a-1941-4af7-aeaa-bf9690f47ee4| 
| 2         | 0     | 5bbc2d06-ed6f-4444-aa22-73820dd6f3f6|
| 2         | 1     | c2bdd9d9-fd47-4727-83f8-02ed0e7537e1|
| 3         | 0     | 8acfa8b4-aa4b-41a7-9d3d-b6ba1eac838e|
| 3         | 1     | 30c18f2d-5d89-4e5d-8e8e-2d2b647d6ab6|
----------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Normally I would agree with you. But doing it in this case requires creating a distinct table with this and then enforcing on that table that exactly 2 entries have the same foreign key. It wouldn't fix this problem just move it. thanks - dave

Comment: I agree that having a separate table and using two foreign keys doesn’t solve the problem, but the DDL I posted does.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand how your DDL works. I have 2 strings, ApiKey1 and ApiKey2 and I need to be able to have each as a distinct column as either is a valid value. Is your DDL creating an additional column that combines the two? Or a unique index that is the combined value of the two? And if a unique index, does that enforce that each key must be unique, or just that the combination must be unique? thanks - dave